# Do I have to install Node for using npm for react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I had uninstalled Node js recently since I didn't have enough space in my drive and I was not doing any back-end projects. But when I tried to run npm commands on VS Code terminal for using react, I get the message:"'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". Should I re-install Node so that I can use npm again? If yes, should I delete all the npm files that are currently existing on my drive?

I have updated all the environmental variables but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes npm is part of node/uses node

Comment: Also none of your react scripts will work without node.

Comment: yes npm comes with the node js, so for any npm command to run node js must be install within the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since NPM stands for NODE Package Manager, it does use Node runtime.

To install node again you can run on your mac `brew install node` if you use windows, I suggest you just enter in node website, download it and install.

If your disk is full, you can delete other things, but node is fundamental to install every package, so it's the last thing you wanna delete.